# Convert [String]? to String in Swift

Tags: arrays, xcode, string, swift

For my project, I extracted tweets from a CSV file in Swift. Problem is now all tweets are parsed as one element in an array, separated by ",".

```
let tweetsOfColumns = columns["tweet"]
let seperatedColumns = tweetsOfColumns.componentsSeparatedByString(",")
```

> Error message: '[String]?' does not have a member named
>   'componentsSeparatedByString'.

I checked if tweetsOfColumns contains multiple elements, but it doesn't allow me to subscript with tweetsOfColumns[index].

Comment: show "tweetsOfColumns" output here ..

Comment: tweetsOfColumns are just a bunch of test-tweets, tweets with handle, hashtags and content. 

     
@dasblinkenlight all of the tweets are saved as one element in an array. I can't seem to access the tweets individually. I would like to do some regex on them to extract handles, hashtags etc.

Comment: Show the declaration/creation of `columns`  My guess from the error message is that it's `[String:[String]]` and not `[String:String]` as answers seem to be assuming.  In which case optional unwrapping is going to get you to `[String]` which doesn't need to be passed to `componentsSeparatedByString` because it already is split up.

Comment: It is indeed returned as [String] instead of String, I can't perform meaningful actions on [String]. The columns is made with the SwiftCSV project on https://github.com/naoty/SwiftCSV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the link you reference, `columns["tweets"]` is going to give you back an array of the values from the "tweets" column, so it's what you need already, there's no additional comma's to split things on, you just need:

```
let seperatedColumns = columns["tweet"]
```

to have an array containing the tweet column for each row.

Comment: Yes this is it, thank you all for your swift help and advice.

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer if one was suitable and answered your question.  (Click the checkmark next to the answer)  That gives folks more incentive to answer questions in the future.

Answer (score 1):

When you try to get an element from a dictionary, like

```
columns["tweet"]
```

it will give you back an optional, because if there is nothing associated with the key, it gives you back nil (None), otherwise the value wrapped in an optional (Some(data)).
So you have to unwrap the optional for example:

```
columns["tweet"]!
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to either use the optional `?` to access the string:

```
let seperatedColumns = tweetsOfColumns?.componentsSeparatedByString(",")
```

But you should unwrap it:

```
if let unwrappedTweets = tweetsOfColumns?.componentsSeparatedByString(","){
    let seperatedColumns = unwrappedTweets
}
```

Comment: If I try to unwrap it via either way the error message keeps coming up:
     
    '[String]' does not have a member named 'componentsSeparatedByString'

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that you'll get an optional back, which you have to unwrap. And the easiest and most elegant is to use the if-let unwrapper.

```
if let tweetsOfColumns = columns["tweet"] {
    let seperatedColumns = tweetsOfColumns.componentsSeparatedByString(",")
    // do something with the seperatedColumns
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on David's question and the OP's response in the OP comments, you can use map on the Array returned by columns["tweet"]. Please post actual data/code in the future.

```
let columns = [
    "tweet":["handleX,tag1,tag2,textA,textB",
             "handleY,tag1,tag2,textC,textD"]]

var chunk = [[String]]()
if columns["tweet"] != nil {
    chunk = columns["tweet"]!.map {
        return $0.componentsSeparatedByString(",")
    }
}
```

[image]